# Powershell variable that contains double and single quotes

Tags: powershell, variables, quotes, sql-server-express, single-quotes

Admittedly noob question...  I'm trying to set up a PowerShell script to create scheduled tasks to backup a SQL Express database.  I'm following the instructions here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/16/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-task-in-new-folder/

They work beautifully for most tasks, but the argument I need to make already contains double and single quotes, and it's throwing everything off.  The argument I have in Task Scheduler is:

```
/C osql -U sa -P Password -S localhost\INSTANCE -Q "Backup Database DATABASE to disk = 'C:\DB Backups\database.bak' with init"
```

With both quotes and single quotes in this, how do I turn this entire string into a variable?

EDIT:  The specific part that's failing is:

```
Function Create-AndRegisterApplogTask

{

 Param ($taskname, $taskpath)

 $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'CMD' -Argument "/C osql -U sa -
P Password -S localhost\INSTANCE -Q "Backup Database DATABASE to disk = 'C:\DB Backups\database.bak' with init""

 $trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 9am

 Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName 
$taskname -Description "Daily Backup of IRWSDB Database" -TaskPath $taskpath

}
```

It's erring because it's seeing

```
"/C osql -U sa -P Cedara123 -S localhost\WEBACCESS -Q "
```

in quotes, then seeing:

```
Backup Database IRWSDB to disk =
```

outside of quote, and then

```
'C:\DB Backups\IRWSDB.bak'
```

in single quotes, followed again by

```
with init
```

outside of quotes finally followed by just:

```
""
```

I've also tried changing the -Argument parameter to just $Argument and trying to declare:

```
$argument = "/C osql -U sa -P Password -S localhost\INSTANCE -Q "Backup Database DATABASE to disk = 'C:\DB Backups\database.bak' with init""
```

But I still can't figure out how to get it to show as a single line of text.

Comment: Please post the _exact_ PowerShell command you are running and explain precisely why it doesn't work.

Comment: Edited with that information

Comment: It's usually easier to put the command you want in a script (batch file) and schedule the script. (This also makes it easier to update the command you want to run - just update the script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the double-quotes inside the string using a backtick. Try:

```
$Arguments = "/C osql -U sa -P Password -S localhost\INSTANCE -Q `"Backup Database DATABASE to disk = 'C:\DB Backups\database.bak' with init`""
```

Usually I end up with a batch-script for the action if the command gets too tricky.

Comment: This worked beautifully!  Thank you!  Honestly, doing a batch script would be ideal, but the actual backup location depends on a registry key and can be different on any server..  So once I verify I can get this working, I have to sub out a few extra parts with variables, including parts of this line, so figuring out how to put this line in was key for me.  Thank you!